# Exoplayer custom overlays

Tags: android

I am using ExoPlayer as a player for my app. I've seen they offer a bunch of ready-to-use player controls that are somewhat customizable, which is in my interest.

However my app has a bunch of other custom controls (i.e. a scoreboard) that I would like to update myself. So if I use exoplayers customization:

```
  <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView android:id="@+id/player"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_controls"/>
```

And i put my scoreboard in this layout, I cannot get ahold of these controls programmatically to update them (or at least I haven't seen any `getPlaybackControls` or `getController` methods).

I would like to take advantage of the builtin timer, play/pause controls, timebar, etc.

Comment: https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlaybackControlView.html

Comment: @pksink this explains what i already know, that you can create custom controls, but how do I get ahold of the `PlaybackControlView` from the `SimpleExoPlayerView`?

Comment: `Specifying a custom layout file` section says: *"This will cause the specified layout to be inflated instead of exo_playback_control_view.xml for only the instance on which the attribute is set"* - so you can simply use `findViewById`

Answer (score 1):

After trying to understand what pskink has said, it really is the case that if you use app:controller_layout_id and specify a PlaybackControlView for SimpleExoPlayerView, you can get any of the elements such as the play, pause, repeat toggle ImageButtons by using findViewById from the SimpleExoPlayerView instance itself rather than trying to inflate the xml representing PlaybackControlView.

Comment: You can simple use it like as given below:

binding.videoPlayer.findViewById(R.id.btn_back).setOnClickListener();

Do what you want by using this view